# Getting IMAP Headers in PHP

Tags: php, email, imap

Hey Guys,
I am totally confused on PHP's imap functions, they are all over the place and I've dug through comments to get this far. I can do **imap_fetchbody($connection, 5, null);** and retrieve the entire message which gives me all that i need:

ie:

> To: user@gmail.com Content-Type:
>   multipart/mixed;
>   boundary=001517570c8a681a5004a36a1fd6
>
> --001517570c8a681a5004a36a1fd6 Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>   boundary=001517570c8a681a4804a36a1fd4
>
> --001517570c8a681a4804a36a1fd4 Content-Type: text/plain;
>   charset=ISO-8859-1
>
> asdf
>
> --001517570c8a681a4804a36a1fd4 Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=ISO-8859-1
>
> asdf
>
> --001517570c8a681a4804a36a1fd4--
>   --001517570c8a681a5004a36a1fd6 Content-Type: image/gif;
>   name="ajax-loader.gif"
>   Content-Disposition: attachment;
>   filename="ajax-loader.gif"
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
>   X-Attachment-Id: f_gnruant80
>
> ... bunch of code here omitted ...

But I really want this information in an Array or Object to use it. **without** having to think up some regular expression to get data out of the entire texts above.

Does anyone know a way to do that or which php imap command to use? Or is there a place with really good examples anyone knows of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a non null value for `section` parameter(3rd parameter). Please see second example of http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php. I think that is what you are searching.